# What's the difference between assertEqual and assertIs (assertIs was introduced in Python 2.7)?

Tags: python, unit-testing

Reference - http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#assert-methods

```
assertEqual(a, b)   # checks that a == b
assertIs(a, b)  # checks that a is b  <---- whatever that means????
```

Comment: When you read the documentation, what exact words confused you?  Did you read about the `==` and the `is` operators?  When you read the difference between the `==` and the `is` operator what exact words confused you?  It helps if you provide quotes of the material you read so that we target the answer to the words that confused you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the semantics of 'is' operator in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438667/what-is-the-semantics-of-is-operator-in-python)

Comment: This answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/python-vs-is-comparing-strings-is-fails-sometimes-why/1504742#1504742

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using `assertEqual` the two objects need not be of the same type, they merely need to be the same value. In comparison, using `assertIs` the two objects need to be the same object.

`assertEqual` tests for equality like the `==` operator:

> The operators <, >, ==, >=, <=, and != compare the values of two objects. The objects need not have the same type. If both are numbers, they are converted to a common type. Otherwise, objects of different types always compare unequal, and are ordered consistently but arbitrarily.

`assertIs` test for object identity same as the `is` and `is not` operators:

> The operators is and is not test for object identity: x is y is true if and only if x and y are the same object. x is not y yields the inverse truth value.

The above quotes both come from the Python documentation section [5.9 Comparisons](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#notin).

Comment: The inequality comparison changed in 3.x versions: Otherwise, the == and != operators always consider objects of different types to be unequal, while the <, >, >= and <= operators raise a TypeError when comparing objects of different types that do not implement these operators for the given pair of types.