# Is this an appropriate use of python's built-in hash function?

Tags: python, hash, hash-collision

I need to compare large chunks of data for equality, and I need to compare many pairs per second, *fast*. Each object is guaranteed to be the same length, it is possible and likely that there may only be slight differences located at unknown positions.

Timings below show that using `==` operator is very fast if there is a difference near the start of the data, and significantly slower if differences are located towards the end.

```
>>> import os
>>> s = os.urandom(1600*1200 - 1)
>>> Aimg = b"A" + s
>>> Bimg = b"B" + s
>>> img1 = s + b"1"
>>> img2 = s + b"2"
>>> %timeit Aimg == Bimg
61.8 ns ± 0.484 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
>>> %timeit img1 == img2
159 µs ± 2.83 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

In my use case, differences may be located towards the middle or the end of the bytes (context: it is uncompressed image data). I looked for a way to speed things up using a hash or checksum. Using md5 was slower but Python's built-in `hash` did actually speed things up.

```
>>> %timeit img1 == img2
160 µs ± 5.96 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
>>> %timeit hash(img1) == hash(img2) and img1 == img2
236 ns ± 5.91 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

I'm interested in technical detail of this hash, is it sufficiently hash-like that when `hash(a) == hash(b)` then `a == b` is *very likely*? False positives are acceptable if a hash collision is reasonably rare, the intention is a fast-path to speed up comparisons in the average case.

Comment: the `hash` function is architecture dependent

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Python's hash function is designed for speed, and maps into a 64-bit space. Due to the [birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), this means you'll likely get a collision at about 5 billion entries (probably way earlier, since the hash function is not cryptographical). Also, the precise definition of `hash` is up to the Python implementation, and may be architecture- or even machine-specific. Don't use it you want the same result on multiple machines.

md5 is designed as a cryptographic hash function; even slight perturbations in the input totally change the output. It also maps into a 128-bit space, which makes it unlikely you'll ever encounter a collision at all unless you're specifically looking for one.

If you can handle collisions (i.e. test for equality between all members in a bucket, possibly by using a cryptographic algorithm like MD5 or SHA2), Python's hash function is perfectly fine.

One more thing: To save space, you should store the data in binary form if you write it to disk. (i.e. `struct.pack('!q', hash('abc'))` / `hashlib.md5('abc').digest()`).

As a side note: [`is`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438667/what-is-the-semantics-of-is-operator-in-python) is not equivalent to `==` in Python. You mean `==`.

Comment: Should this be `!q` rather than `!I` ? The example `struct.pack('!I', hash('abc'))` gives me `struct.error: 'I' format requires 0 <= number <= 4294967295`.

Comment: @AndyHayden Indeed. Fixed.