# Avoid copying the whole vector when replacing an element (a[1] <- 2)

Tags: r

When replacing an element in a vector such as

```
a <- 1:1000000
a[1] <- 2
```

R copies the whole vector, replaces the element in the new vector, and then do the variable name re-association. I was wondering anyway to override or prevent this to make it behave something more like c array?

Thanks

Comment: @ Shen: Welcome to the SO. Can you please provide [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: just add an example, thanks

Comment: Sorry, I am still not clear what are you asking here. Can you post expected output for example, `a<-1:10`?

Comment: @Metrics I think the OP is saying that the step following, subassignment `?\`[<-\``, makes a full copy of a. I don't see that mentioned in the documentation, but it sounds familiar.

Comment: With base R, that is the behavior, unfortunately. The language is memory inefficient compared to others. You could try the package `Rcpp` to get better speed.

Comment: @Metrics Sorry that I didn't make it clear. The question is not about the output but internal memory management. It seems R will make an internal copy before the amending, which slows down the code for my purpose. You can see this by using system.time(a[1]<-2) or tracemem(). Thank you!

Comment: This can be interesting too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424422/first-bracketed-assignment-is-as-time-consuming-as-full-assignment

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `tracemem` function (R needs to be compiled to support it) provides an indication of when copying occurs. Here's what you do

```
> a <- 1:1000000; tracemem(a)
[1] "<0x7f791b39e010>"
> a[1] = 2
tracemem[0x7f791b39e010 -> 0x7f791a9d4010]:
```

and indeed there's a copy. But this is because you're coercing `a` from an integer vector (`1:1000000` creates a sequence of integers) to a numeric vector (because `2` is a numeric value, and R coerces to a common type). If instead you update your integer vector with an integer value, or a numeric vector with a numeric value, there is no copying

```
> a <- 1:1000000; tracemem(a)
[1] "<0x7f791a4ef010>"
> a[1] = 2L
> a = c(1, 2, 3); tracemem(a)
[1] "<0x5180470>"
> a[1] = 2
>
```

A little bit further insight comes from understanding at a superficial level how R's memory management works. Each allocation has a NAMED level associated with it. NAMED=0 or 1 indicates that there is at most 1 symbol that refers to it; it is therefore safe to copy in place. NAMED=2 means that there is, or has been, at least 2 symbols pointing to the same location, and that any attempt to update the value requires a duplication to preserve R's illusion of 'copy on change'. The following reveals some of the internal structure of `a`, including that it of type INTSXP (integer) with NAM(1) (NAMED level 1) and that it's being TRaced. Hence updating (with an integer!) does not require a copy.

```
> a = 1:10; tracemem(a); .Internal(inspect(a))
[1] "<0x5170818>"
@5170818 13 INTSXP g0c4 [NAM(1),TR] (len=10, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5,...
> a[1] = 2L
>
```

On the other had, here two symbols refer to the location in memory, hence NAMED is 2 and a copy is required

```
> a = b = 1:10; tracemem(a); .Internal(inspect(a))
[1] "<0x576d1a0>"
@576d1a0 13 INTSXP g0c4 [NAM(2),TR] (len=10, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5,...
> a[1] = 2L
tracemem[0x576d1a0 -> 0x576d148]:
```

It is difficult to reason about NAMED, so at some level these types of games have a level of futility about them.

`inspect` returns other information. Each R type is represented internally as an 'SEXP' (S-expression) type. These are enumerate, and the 13th SEXP type is an integer SEXP -- hence `13 INTSXP`. Check out `.Internal(inspect(...))` for a numeric vector, character vector, or even function `.Internal(inspect(function() {}))`.

R manages memory by periodically running a 'garbage collector' that checks to see if memory is currently referenced; if it is not, then it is reclaimed for use by another symbol. The garbage collector is 'generational', which means that recently allocated memory is checked for reclamation more frequently than older memory (this is because, empirically, variables tend to have a short half-life, e.g., for the duration of a function call, so recently allocated memory is more likely to be available for reclamation than memory that has been in use for a longer time). The `g0c4` and similar annotations are providing information about the generation the SEXP belongs to.

The `TR` represents a 'bit' set in the SEXP to indicate that the variable is being traced; it was set when we said `tracemem(a)`.

Some of these topics are discussed in the documentation of R's internal implementation `RShowDoc("R-ints")` and in the C header file Rinternals.h.

Comment: Thank you! Very interesting and helpful! I was wondering what are 13 g0c4 TR and tl stands for in the output from inspect?

Comment: @Shen I added a section on this to my answer, with references to the R internals manual and source code.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with the [ff](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/index.html) package which is on CRAN. Using ff, your data is stored on disk and indexing will only affect that specific element you are indexing

```
require(ff)
a <- ff(1:1000000)
a[1] <- 2
```

For info. These are timings, so it is a lot faster for your toy case.

```
require(ff)
a <- 1:100000000
b <- ff(a)
system.time(a[1] <- 2)
 user  system elapsed 
0.440   0.592   1.056 
system.time(b[1] <- 2)
 user  system elapsed 
0.004   0.000   0.001
```

Comment: Oh! Interesting! Does IO to the disk make it slow in this case?

Comment: @Shen  If you load the `microbenchmark` package, it's easy to run timing tests for your specific code variations.

Comment: Depends on your hardware but it is pretty fast. Added timings for your toy example.