# R programming: avoid copying the whole data frame when amending?

Tags: r, dataframe

It seems that R copies the whole dataframe when amending one entry in a data frame. I was wondering if there was a way to make R just copy the corresponding data column (e.g. a specific INTSXP below instead of the VECSXP) to maintain copy-on-change policy? Also is there way to do amend-in-place for dataframes?

```
> x<-data.frame(x=1:1000000,y=1:1000000)
> .Internal(inspect(x))
@62cd2b0 19 VECSXP g0c2 [OBJ,MARK,NAM(2),ATT] (len=2, tl=0)
  @f80d0e0 13 INTSXP g0c7 [MARK] (len=1000000, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5,...
  @8ed6970 13 INTSXP g0c7 [] (len=1000000, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5,...
ATTRIB:
  @68f6b40 02 LISTSXP g0c0 []
    TAG: @4e58868 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,LCK,gp=0x4000] "names" (has value)
    @613efd0 16 STRSXP g0c2 [] (len=2, tl=0)
      @4e93038 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "x"
      @4fe8bd8 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "y"
    TAG: @4e62650 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,LCK,gp=0x4000] "row.names" (has value)
    @113bb328 13 INTSXP g0c1 [] (len=2, tl=0) -2147483648,-1000000
    TAG: @4e58d38 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,LCK,gp=0x4000] "class" (has value)
    @113aa1d8 16 STRSXP g0c1 [MARK,NAM(2)] (len=1, tl=0)
      @4ee78a0 09 CHARSXP g1c2 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "data.frame"
> x[1,1]<-3L
>  .Internal(inspect(x))
@68eb9f8 19 VECSXP g0c2 [OBJ,NAM(2),ATT] (len=2, tl=0)
  @6507290 13 INTSXP g0c7 [] (len=1000000, tl=0) 3,2,3,4,5,...
  @7422920 13 INTSXP g0c7 [] (len=1000000, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5,...
ATTRIB:
  @68ef738 02 LISTSXP g0c0 []
    TAG: @4e58868 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,LCK,gp=0x4000] "names" (has value)
    @68ebaa0 16 STRSXP g0c2 [NAM(2)] (len=2, tl=0)
      @4e93038 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "x"
      @4fe8bd8 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "y"
    TAG: @4e62650 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,LCK,gp=0x4000] "row.names" (has value)
    @f43c418 13 INTSXP g0c1 [] (len=2, tl=0) -2147483648,-1000000
    TAG: @4e58d38 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,LCK,gp=0x4000] "class" (has value)
    @f43c4d8 16 STRSXP g0c1 [NAM(1)] (len=1, tl=0)
      @4ee78a0 09 CHARSXP g1c2 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "data.frame"
```

Thank you!

Shen

Comment: possible duplicate of [R Programming: vector a\[1\]<-2 avoid copying the whole vector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359940/r-programming-vector-a1-2-avoid-copying-the-whole-vector)

Comment: @Metrics not the same

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652533/insert-a-row-in-a-data-table/16994870#16994870) - modify element in `data.table` in place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `data.table` for this, it is done for exactly this purpose. And read [this reference post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225098/understanding-exactly-when-a-data-table-is-a-reference-to-vs-a-copy-of-another/14293056#14293056)

```
R) dt<-data.table(x=1:10,y=1:10)
R) .Internal(inspect(dt))
@0x000000000dce56c0 19 VECSXP g0c7 [OBJ,NAM(1),ATT] (len=2, tl=100)
  @0x000000000ebc4100 13 INTSXP g0c4 [NAM(2)] (len=10, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5,...
  @0x000000000ebc41b0 13 INTSXP g0c4 [NAM(2)] (len=10, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5,...
ATTRIB:
  @0x000000000e6c2d00 02 LISTSXP g0c0 [] 
    TAG: @0x00000000003b0088 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,LCK,gp=0x4000] "names" (has value)
    @0x000000000cc99fd0 16 STRSXP g0c7 [NAM(2)] (len=2, tl=100)
      @0x00000000003ddbb8 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "x"
      @0x000000000734f4d8 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "y"
    TAG: @0x00000000003b1d98 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,LCK,gp=0x4000] "row.names" (has value)
    @0x0000000014487f98 13 INTSXP g0c1 [] (len=2, tl=0) -2147483648,-10
    TAG: @0x00000000003b0558 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,LCK,gp=0x4000] "class" (has value)
    @0x000000000ead1910 16 STRSXP g0c2 [] (len=2, tl=0)
      @0x000000000753f440 09 CHARSXP g1c2 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "data.table"
      @0x000000000715f398 09 CHARSXP g1c2 [MARK,gp=0x61,ATT] [ASCII] [cached] "data.frame"
    TAG: @0x000000000c3d7cc0 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK] ".internal.selfref"
    @0x000000000e6c1e80 22 EXTPTRSXP g0c0 [] 
R) dt[,y:=y+1]
R) .Internal(inspect(dt))
@0x000000000dce56c0 19 VECSXP g0c7 [OBJ,NAM(2),ATT] (len=2, tl=100)
  @0x000000000ebc4100 13 INTSXP g0c4 [NAM(2)] (len=10, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5,...
  @0x000000000ebc6728 14 REALSXP g0c6 [NAM(1)] (len=10, tl=0) 2,3,4,5,6,...
ATTRIB:
  @0x000000000e6c2d00 02 LISTSXP g0c0 [] 
    TAG: @0x00000000003b0088 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,LCK,gp=0x4000] "names" (has value)
    @0x000000000cc99fd0 16 STRSXP g0c7 [NAM(2)] (len=2, tl=100)
      @0x00000000003ddbb8 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "x"
      @0x000000000734f4d8 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "y"
    TAG: @0x00000000003b1d98 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,LCK,gp=0x4000] "row.names" (has value)
    @0x0000000014487f98 13 INTSXP g0c1 [] (len=2, tl=0) -2147483648,-10
    TAG: @0x00000000003b0558 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,LCK,gp=0x4000] "class" (has value)
    @0x000000000ead1910 16 STRSXP g0c2 [NAM(2)] (len=2, tl=0)
      @0x000000000753f440 09 CHARSXP g1c2 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "data.table"
      @0x000000000715f398 09 CHARSXP g1c2 [MARK,gp=0x61,ATT] [ASCII] [cached] "data.frame"
    TAG: @0x000000000c3d7cc0 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK] ".internal.selfref"
    @0x000000000e6c1e80 22 EXTPTRSXP g0c0 []
```

Comment: To do what he's doing, `dt[1,1:=3L,with=FALSE]` actually works (surprisingly)

Comment: you mean `dt[1,x:=3L]` ?

Comment: No - that works too obviously, I'm trying to make it fit the OP's example (getting to replace an element by its row/column number)

Answer (score 5):

@stat_quant is correct that `data.table` is the way to go.

However  `data.table` has a function `set` that will modify `data.frames` in place as well (*modify* but  **not** *extend*)

With a smaller example

```
x <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
# @0x00000000120dbca8 19 VECSXP g0c2 [OBJ,NAM(2),ATT] (len=2, tl=0)
#   @0x0000000011631328 13 INTSXP g0c4 [] (len=10, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5,...
#   @0x0000000011631380 13 INTSXP g0c4 [] (len=10, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5,...
# ATTRIB:
#   @0x0000000020964420 02 LISTSXP g0c0 [] 
#   TAG: @0x0000000000330088 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,NAM(2),LCK,gp=0x4000] "names" (has value)
#   @0x00000000120dafe8 16 STRSXP g0c2 [NAM(1)] (len=2, tl=0)
#     @0x000000000037dc60 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "x"
#     @0x0000000008dc35c0 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "y"
#   TAG: @0x0000000000331d98 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,LCK,gp=0x4000] "row.names" (has value)
#   @0x000000001165e700 13 INTSXP g0c1 [] (len=2, tl=0) -2147483648,-10
#   TAG: @0x0000000000330558 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,LCK,gp=0x4000] "class" (has value)
#   @0x000000001165e730 16 STRSXP g0c1 [NAM(2)] (len=1, tl=0)
#     @0x00000000003fc4a0 09 CHARSXP g1c2 [MARK,gp=0x61,ATT] [ASCII] [cached] "data.frame"
.Internal(inspect(x))
set(x,i=1L,j=1L,value = 3L)
.Internal(inspect(x))
# @0x00000000120dbca8 19 VECSXP g0c2 [OBJ,NAM(2),ATT] (len=2, tl=0)
#   @0x0000000011631328 13 INTSXP g0c4 [] (len=10, tl=0) 3,2,3,4,5,...
#   @0x0000000011631380 13 INTSXP g0c4 [] (len=10, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5,...
# ATTRIB:
#   @0x0000000020964420 02 LISTSXP g0c0 [] 
#   TAG: @0x0000000000330088 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,NAM(2),LCK,gp=0x4000] "names" (has value)
#   @0x00000000120dafe8 16 STRSXP g0c2 [NAM(2)] (len=2, tl=0)
#     @0x000000000037dc60 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "x"
#   @0x0000000008dc35c0 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "y"
#   TAG: @0x0000000000331d98 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,LCK,gp=0x4000] "row.names" (has value)
#   @0x000000001165e700 13 INTSXP g0c1 [] (len=2, tl=0) -2147483648,-10
#   TAG: @0x0000000000330558 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,LCK,gp=0x4000] "class" (has value)
#   @0x000000001165e730 16 STRSXP g0c1 [NAM(2)] (len=1, tl=0)
#     @0x00000000003fc4a0 09 CHARSXP g1c2 [MARK,gp=0x61,ATT] [ASCII] [cached] "data.frame"
head(x)
#   x y
# 1 3 1
# 2 2 2
# 3 3 3
# 4 4 4
# 5 5 5
# 6 6 6
```

With `set` you can change values within existing columns of a `data.frame`, you cannot add columns (as you can with `:=` and `data.table`)

Comment: Spot on `set` it was actaully a better answer