# Why is this insertion fast in R?

Tags: r, performance, vector, insert

Consider the following code:

```
lotsOfNumbers <- rep(pi, 5 * 10^7) 
system.time(lotsOfNumbers[1] <- 0)
```

If I enter one line of code at a time, the second line of code takes about 0.267 seconds to evaluate on my computer. This is not surprising to me: I know that the R code `lotsOfNumbers[1] <- 0` actually recopies `lotsOfNumbers` into a new object, so this function actually scales with the length of lotsOfNumbers rather than being constant.

What **is** surprising to me is that if you enter both lines of code at the same time, `system.time` will report that the second line of code takes 0.000 seconds on my computer.

Why would entering both lines at the same time speed up the second line?

Comment: Interesting...  Not an answer but maybe a clue: encapsulate your first line in a system.time() call as well. Then running both lines at the same time or running them one by one makes no difference in the durations.

Comment: @DominicComtois: yes, I had noticed this...but then if you run further lines of code like the second one (i.e. `system.time(lotsOfNumbers[1] <- 1`), they are fast (even though the second one is still slow).

Comment: Intreaguing... maybe a glitch in the system.time function? I tried running it in batch mode, and have the same odd time of 0 at the end.

Comment: @TheTime It is... with `pryr` you can validate that, see http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html

Comment: I'm going to guess you're using RStudio. Am I right? If so, to see why I guessed that (and why you're seeing the behavior you are), [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15559956/980833) especially the section leading up to and including the 3rd code block.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I replicated the phenomenon using Rscript.exe...

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: Ah yes! I think you've got it there. Going to read through a little more on that post...

Comment: @DominicComtois How do you enter those lines one at a time using Rscript?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Well obviously I don't. It was to outrule the influence of the interface factor (Rstudio or else)

Comment: @CliffAB -- Hmm. That's odd. I don't see that using R (via Rgui on a Windows 7 box). The call to `system.time(lotsOfNumbers[2] <- 0)` takes 0 seconds in either case (i.e. whether the lines are entered together or one after the other).

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: yes, you are correct. I had only replicated the slow part in R (i.e. entering both at the same time) so I thought they were identical. But you are correct, using R the insertion is fast, even if broken up. So I'm now buying your Rstudio argument (sorry, I edited my earlier comment where I disagreed with that).

Comment: @DominicComtois -- Likewise, on my Windows 7 box, using Rscript gets me timings of 0 seconds across the board. Wonder what's going on.

Comment: Re: in-place or not, in RStudio the vector is indeed copied when modifying 1st item (no need to use system.time for that to happen). But in a "terminal" R.exe session, it is modified in-place. Boy, still puzzled here.

Comment: @TheTime Oh I wouldn't _sue_ them for that tho :p  ... But in any case, the behavior of system.time is still weird even in batch mode!

Comment: @TheTime Hmm not sure I'm following. Are we talking about the same issue? Here's what I put in the script to run via Rscript.exe (on 3 separate lines): `system.time(lotsOfNumbers <- rep(pi, 5e7))  
system.time(lotsOfNumbers[1] <- 0)  
system.time(lotsOfNumbers[2] <- 0)`

Comment: @DominicComtois Probably not talking about the exact same issue. Your example is highlighting the fact that the version of `lotsOfNumbers` returned by the call to `system.time()` has `NAM[2]` whereas that created outside of `system.time()` has `NAM[1]`. (To see this, compare: `system.time(X <- rep(pi, 5e7)); .Internal(inspect(X)); Y <- rep(pi, 5e7); .Internal(inspect(Y))`.) This in turn affects whether  or not the entire object gets copied over when performing a simple replacement.