# Does R always copy data in RStudio?

Tags: r, memory, memory-management, rstudio

In Advanced R, Hadley Wickham writes

> When `refs(x)` is 1, modification will occur in place. When `refs(x)` is 2, R will make a copy (this ensures that other pointers to the object remain unaffected).

But also

> Note that if you’re using RStudio, `refs()` will always return 2: the
>   environment browser makes a reference to every object you create on
>   the command line.

Does that mean that in RStudio, R will always copy data, and never modify it in place, because `refs()` will always return 2?

Comment: Since the environment browser only captures symbols at the top level, it seems like R's memory copy behavior within functions or other closures would not be affected.

Comment: Related: [Operator “[<-” in RStudio and R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559387/operator-in-rstudio-and-r).