# Why is r not modifying in place in this situation?

Tags: r

```
> z <- 1:10
> lobstr::obj_addr(z)
[1] "0x564d8d9eaac8"

> z[[3]] <- 4L
> lobstr::obj_addr(z)
[1] "0x564d882b4328"
```

Why is the address different after the modifcation?
This should be an in place modification, no?

Comment: @akrun lobstr is the package name

Comment: @user20650 yes, does that matter?

Comment: The following chapter in advanced R is helpful on this.   2.3 Copy-on-modify 

Wickham, Hadley. Advanced R, Second Edition (Chapman & Hall/CRC The R Series) (p. 22). CRC Press. Kindle Edition.

Comment: I assume you are running this in Rstudio? The IDE keeps a reference to the object to show in the environments window which interferes with in-place modification. If you ran this in the standard R GUI you would see that the address is the same.

Answer (score 4):

Earlier questions (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15559956/2761575)) explain some of the aspects of when R performs a copy.  However, there is an additional nuance in OP's example that is worth highlighting here.  Note that, the following code has been executed in an R console, not in RStudio.  As others have [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15559956/2761575) pointed out, Rstudio has its own impacts on the process, which we eliminate here by working directly in R.

R's "copy on modify behaviour" can be complicated.  R will try to conduct the replacement in place, *whenever possible*.  But, there's an interesting reason that this is not one those situations where it can do so.  This is related to the "AltRep" (Alternative Representation) optimizations brought in since R 3.5.0.  One such optimization is the ability to store contiguous sequences of numbers using just their end members, rather than allocating the entire vector.  See [here](https://svn.r-project.org/R/branches/ALTREP/ALTREP.html#compact_integer_vectors) for more details.

Let's try to see what is going on in this case using `.Internal(inspect(z))` to glimpse the internals of the object representation, and `tracemem` to detect when an object has been copied:

```
x = 1L:10L
tracemem(x)
# [1] "<0x559377dba830>"
.Internal(inspect(x))
# @559377dba830 13 INTSXP g0c0 [NAM(7),TR]  1 : 10 (compact)
```

As we can see, at this stage the `1:10` is represented in the form 1:10 (compact). This means that the full sequence has not yet been explicitly evaluated or allocated.  Only a compact representation of its start and end values exists for now..

Now when we assign into an element of the vector, we see that the object does get copied:

```
x[[3]] = 4L
# tracemem[0x559377dba830 -> 0x559376ae1e48]:
```

And we can also see that the internals of the object were also changed into an explicit vector of integers rather than the 1:10 "compact" form:

```
.Internal(inspect(x))
# @559376ae1e48 13 INTSXP g0c4 [NAM(1),TR] (len=10, tl=0) 1,2,4,4,5,...
```

Now, compare this to the following version in which a copy does *not* get triggered (because the initial vector was already in its expanded (not compact) form):

```
x = c(1L:10L)
tracemem(x)
# [1] "<0x55d6146772d8>"
.Internal(inspect(x))
# @55d6146772d8 13 INTSXP g0c4 [NAM(1),TR] (len=10, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5,...

x[[3]] = 4L
# No copying occured here!!
```