# Test if two `data.table`s point to the same memory location

Tags: r, data.table

Let's have:

```
DT1 <- data.table(iris)
DT2 <- DT1 # both reference the same memory location though
DT3 <- copy(DT1)
```

**Question:** Is there a way to check that `DT2` keeps referencing the same memory location as `DT1`?

Something like this pseudo-function:

```
mem.identical(DT2, DT1) # should return TRUE
mem.identical(DT3, DT1) # should return FALSE
```

---

Unfortunately, `identical` or `all.equal` don't work for this purpose, because

```
identical(DT1,DT3) # gives TRUE
```

Only after introducing some change, the difference can be detected using `identical`:

```
DT1[,Test:=1] # introduces change to DT1 directly, to DT2 indirectly
identical(DT1,DT2) # TRUE - proves that DT2 is linked with DT1
identical(DT1,DT3) # FALSE - DT1 and DT3 are clearly decoupled
```

Comment: Here's a different question with a duplicate answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10913296/403310 (that I only found because it's linked in the documentation for `address`)

Comment: @BenBolker actually the value added is `data.table::address` solution by @GSee, which I didn't find elsewhere

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `data.table::address` for this

```
> address(DT1)
[1] "0x10336c230"
> address(DT2)
[1] "0x10336c230"
> address(DT3)
[1] "0x10336cb50"
```

Comment: (+1), but you should probably mention that this is `data.table` library function..

Comment: @DavidArenburg I didn't think it was necessary because the Question includes `data.table` in the title, it is tagged [data.table] and the first line of code to create the sample data is `DT1 <- data.table(iris)`. ;-)

Comment: Hadley also has an `address` function in his **pryr** package (https://github.com/hadley/pryr/blob/master/R/inspect.r) that serves the same purpose, but since `data.table` is already loaded there's no reason to load another package.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found the answer [on SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225098/understanding-exactly-when-a-data-table-is-a-reference-to-vs-a-copy-of-another), using `tracemem`:

```
DT1 <- data.table(iris)
DT2 <- DT1
DT3 <- copy(DT1)

identical(tracemem(DT1),tracemem(DT2)) # TRUE
identical(tracemem(DT1),tracemem(DT3)) # FALSE
```

Comment: Please, remember you need to call untracemem after call tracemem, otherwise you'll get a message every time DT1, DT2 or DT3 change...

Comment: Since you found the answer on SO, you should probably vote to close (if you have sufficient rep) *or* comment (if you don't) rather than just copying the answer? (I admit I haven't looked to see whether there's any value-added in your answer over the original ...)

Comment: Ok will do accordingly next time, instead of copying the answer, wasn't sure about proper SO etiquette. Thanks @BenBolker