# Why str(None) is not str(None)?

Tags: python, string

I have an object converted to a string using str(object). I would like to check, using the string, if I had a None object (in my case it would never be 'None' unless the object is None).

```
string = str(object) // object is None
if string is 'None' or string is str(None):
  // do something
```

The problem is the condition never passes. How can I check this case?

The same way **str(None) is str(None)** returns False. Why?

Comment: You've confused equality with identity. Try `string == 'None' or string == str(None)`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988017/string-comparison-in-python-is-vs or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce

Comment: Careful not to override the built in `object` constructor by using it as a variable name...

Comment: Do not use `object` as a variable name! `>:-(`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string conversions of another object will in general not be the same object each time the conversion is made; it makes a new string each time.  the `is` operator compares identity, not value. You want `==`

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> str(l) is str(l)
False
>>> str(l) == str(l)
True
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if object is None:
    print("the object is None")
else:
    print("the object exists")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
if string == 'None':
   # Do something.
```

Check out [What is the semantics of 'is' operator in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438667/what-is-the-semantics-of-is-operator-in-python) for the meaning of 'is` in python.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `object` is a pre-defined class, the common ancestor of all classes. However, it has nothing to do with your question.

After calling `string = str(None)`, the variable string holds 'None', a python string. You can call `type(string) # should be <type 'str'>` to confirm it. To solve this issue, you can replace it with:

- **string == 'None'**
- **string == str(None)**
- **if object is None** Matches None and nothing else.
- **if object** Match all falsy values

Answer (score 1):

Check for None with Nonetype any time you know None is a valid possibility.  In fact, unless the return string you get passed in is the string value 'None', you should not design your app to check for this possibility with string comparisons anyway.  Notwithstanding the is vs == operator differences.